# Why elasticsearch cannot support min_doc_count and order by _count asc?

Tags: elasticsearch

Requirements:

```
group by hldId having count(*) = 2
```

Elasticsearch query:

```
"aggs": {
    "groupByHldId": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "hldId",
            "min_doc_count": 2,
            "order" : { "_count" : "asc" }
        }            
    }
}
```

but no records are return

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "groupByHldId" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : -1,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 2660,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
```

but if changed to `desc` , it has return

```
   "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 200035075,
          "doc_count" : 355
        },
```

or if without `min_doc_count`, it also has return

```
"buckets" : [    
    {
      "key" : 200000061,
      "doc_count" : 1
    },
```

So why both have `mid_doc_count` and `asc` direction it returns empty?

Comment: This  is interressing. It seems that sort is done before the min_doc_count. So es sort the data, keeing only X (=size) elemnts in the bucket selector and then apply min_doc_count. So obviously it work with a DESC but not with a ASC.

Comment: Your explanation should be right. If I set size larger e.g. 5000 then it has return

Comment: Should be possible to do it using a custom score (but would affect performance for sure)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, `bucket selector` with a custom `script`.

```
 {
  "aggs": {
    "countfield": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "hldId",
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "criticals": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "doc_count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.doc_count==2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works (and it should be  `params.doc_count==2` ) but I want to know why min_doc_count and asc not work